# style missing in vue component library with vite and tailwind

Tags: vue.js, tailwind-css, vite

we are trying to create a reusable vue component library with tailwindcss. tailwind is not bundled with the library, the consuming application has to install and configure tailwind.

When the library is imported into the consuming application, it is some of the tailwind classes are not applied to the component even though they are referenced by the component.

In the library project, the component looks like this:

[image: expected view]

and in the consuming application, it looks like this:

[image]

The pr-3 padding is not applied. when I inspect the HTML, I can  see the class is referenced by the dev element:

[image]

But there is no style associated with it.

library configuration:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import path from 'path'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/libs/index.js'),
      name: 'uipack',
      fileName: (format) => `uipack.${format}.js`
    },
    target: 'esnext',
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ['vue', 'tailwindcss', '@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio', '@tailwindcss/forms', '@tailwindcss/typography'],
      output: {
        exports: 'named'
      }
    }
  }
})
```

the library plugin:

```
import * as components from './components'

const uipack = {
  install(app) {
    Object.keys(components).forEach((name) => {
      app.component(name, components[name])
    })
  }
}

export default uipack
```

This is the tailwindcss configuration in the library project, but tailwindcss is not imported directly by any of the components and is not added to the vite build.

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ['./src/libs/**/*.{html,vue,js}'],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        sans: ['Raleway', 'sans-serif']
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [require('@tailwindcss/typography'), require('@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio'), require('@tailwindcss/forms')]
}
```

The consuming application has a similar tailwindcss configuration:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ['./index.html', './src/**/*.{vue,js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        sans: ['Raleway', 'sans-serif']
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [require('@tailwindcss/typography'), require('@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio'), require('@tailwindcss/forms')]
}
```

Some of the classes are applied just a few of them, like the colors and padding are not applied even though referenced by the element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by making sure Tailwind can scan my component files.

[Tailwind Documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#working-with-third-party-libraries)

> If you’ve created your own reusable set of components that are styled
> with Tailwind and are importing them in multiple projects, make sure
> to configure Tailwind to scan those components for class names:

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './components/**/*.{html,js}',
    './pages/**/*.{html,js}',
    **'./node_modules/@my-company/tailwind-components/**/*.js',**
  ],
  // ...
}
```